# как получить сумму значений переменных в цикле for

Tags: javascript

как на JS получить сумму переменных обрабатываемых в цикле for ? и вынести эту сумму за цикл ?

```js
for( let i = 0; i < shopping.length; i++ ){
  let a = parseFloat( shopping[i].innerText );
  let b = parseFloat( views[i].innerText );

}
```

К примеру как получить вне цикла сумму значений переменной "a" за все циклы ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = shopping.reduce((res, item) => res + parseFloat(item.innerText), 0);
```

Comment: только, скорее всего, нужно начать с `Array.from(shopping)`